# Joomla Template Selection

Tags: joomla

I am planning to build Auto responsive website in Joomla. I am looking for below features.

Must have :

- Auto responsive (mobile friendly)
- Static & Dynamic content management
- Forms submission
- Auto email on form submit
- CRM entry on form submit using an API call to our CRM

Good to have :

- Ticket Raising system
- FAQ managment
- Backup Of Site
- Blog handing

Kindly advise, which template can be used to achieve above functions?

Comment: Joomla 3.x is responsive and use RSform component for ticketing and auto emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Joomla 3's standard template as it's responsive, however there are so many sites using this so you go down another road.

If you're up for some design of your own, then you can get a pre-built master template such as [Yootheme's Master Theme](https://www.yootheme.com/blog/2012/02/13/master-theme) which is free or maybe ever [Afterburner 2](http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla-downloads/free/3420-afterburner2) by Rockettheme.

For forms, you can use an extension such as [Chronoforms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508) which allows you to build your own forms for multiple purposes and has a lot of features.

As for the **"Good to have"** points, simply have a search on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) and you will find everything you need.

Hope this helps

Comment: Lodder,
Appreciate your reply. Your suggestions would be helpful. 

I am very new at Joomla. The themes you advised seem good. I was also wondering if there's a website where I can check the user reviews of the various templates. I've seen bestofjoomla.com and wanted to check if there's another place for the review too. Just need to make sure that the template has a number of features that offers us flexibility.

Comment: Also, regarding the forms, we need to make a form involving 3-4 pages. Hence need the functionality that the user can leave half completed form and come back, login and complete it. 

We've tried RSForms but unfortunately that feature is not there. Wondering if this category of forms is called something else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Only one of your requirements has anything to do with the template you choose, whether it is responsive or not.

Joomla templates do nothing more than provide styling for the output of Joomla core and any extensions you may add. Everything you list is functionality that would need to be added with 3rd-party extensions, with the exception of content management; Joomla is a Content Management System.